# How to send a GTM variable over as an event in GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Through Google Tag Manager, I have successfully made a connection to track page views for my company site.  I have debugged this in GTM and also see the "real time" results loading in Google Analytics.  But I want to take things further than just page views being tracked. I want to track a GTM variable as a GA event.

**For the same Google Tag Manager Workspace**, I went to the "Variables" page and created a new variable called "Certain HTML Element Class Name". The point of the variable is to collect the class name found on my `<html>` element. For example, collect **cat** from:

```
<html class="cat">
....
</html>
```

I am successful in seeing this value displayed in GTM's debug window.

**But!!!** **How in the world do I send that variable data to Google Analytics as an event**?  I want to see from Google Analytics that every time a page is loaded, GA fires my GTM variable as an event.

Is this possible?

Just to show what I have attempted to do - here are my settings in GTM. Am I on the right track??? Am I missing something? Appreciate any feedback!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I feel this is closer to the truth in solving my issue.

- From GTM, I went into my existing workspace and created a second Tag.  I called this one **IT Apps Certain Event Tracking**. For the settings...

  - I assigned the **GA Universal Analytics**.
  - I then assigned the Track type to **Event**.
  - I then filled in the Action, label and value fields.  For value, I assigned `{{Certain HTML Element Class Name}}`.
  - For Google Analytic Settings, I assigned my `{{Google Analytics Settings}}` variable.
  - Finally, I attached my trigger, **IT Apps - Certain Page Views**.

After publishing these settings in GTM, I was able to go into the GA and see my events firing under the "Real time" section.  I feel happy about this and can't wait until I start seeing my results (values) for my events kicking in.

Comment: Thanks for sharing!